# Webpack: Why 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader' doesn't process imported files?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, autoprefixer, postcss

I have page.css that @imports index.css.

Both of page.css and index.css has `display: flex`.

Webpack.config.js contains:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader" }
    ]
},
postcss: function () {
    return [ autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 5 versions'] }) ];
}
```

After building I got prefixes in rules from page.css but rules from index.css left without prefixes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [postcss-import](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import) plugin to transform @import rules by inlining content.

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader" }
    ]
},
postcss: function () {

    return [ 
        require('postcss-import')(),
        autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 5 versions'] })
    ];
}
```

Comment: thank you. It works, but when i add css background with image, i got Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./background.png. Btw, i have { test: /(\.png|\.jpg)$/, loader: "file-loader" } that worked well before adding autoprefixer.